# Make regex more readable

Tags: regex, perl

I have a long reggex like this:
`if( $var =~ /(word1|word2|word3|word4)/` but actually I have much more than 4 words and they are much bigger.
How can I add new lines to make it more readable without breaking the reggex?
E.g.

```
if($var =~ /(word1 |  
                  word2 |  etc
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%2fx

Answer (score 6):

Add the `/x` modifier which ignores whitespace in the regex:

```
if ($var =~ / ( word1 |  
                word2 |
                word3
              )/x
    ) {
```

You can also build the regex from a list by joining the words by `|` and using the `qr` operator to create a regex:

```
my $regex = join '|', qw( word1
                          word2
                          word3
                        );
$regex = qr/($regex)/;
```

Comment: It would be useful if you explained what the commands do.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your regular expression more readable by... not using a regular expression in the first place. If your real code is actually as straightforward as your example (i.e., just matching alternate strings without any pattern matching), why not use a hash instead?

```
my $var = 'word1';
my %lookup = map { $_ => 1 } qw(word1 word2 word3 word4);

if ($lookup{$var}) {
    # do something...
}
```

Comment: That equivalent to `/^(word1|word2|word3|word4)\z/`, not `/(word1|word2|word3|word4)/`. But that could very well be what the OP wants.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I was reading into the question a little. It's not very clear and doesn't contain actual code, so it's hard to say.

Comment: No I don't want it to be start of line or end of line.

Comment: @ikegami:You are right. I want `/(word1|word2|word3|word4)/`